# Navigation with Fragment that takes a parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

My application consists of a `ViewPager` that contains `9 Fragments` of the same type. This Fragment takes a parameter in its constructor upon declaration as shown below.

**NewsFragment.kt**

```kotlin
class NewsFragment(section: NewsSection) : Fragment() {
   //...
}
```

**CategoryFragmentPagerAdapter.kt**

```kotlin
class CategoryFragmentPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager)
    : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment =
        NewsFragment(NewsSection.getItem(position))

    override fun getCount(): Int = NewsSection.values().size

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence =
         NewsSection.getItem(position).sectionName

}
```

And this fragment contains some actions which should navigate the user to some other fragments.

I tried to implement the navigation using the `Jetpack Navigation Component` method but looks it gives an error because the navigation graph can't accept a fragment with a parameter.

Any ideas on how to implement the `Navigation` in such a situation?

### Edit

---

So this is my `FragmentContainerView` in the activity's `XML layout`

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation" />
```

and this is how I implement the `navController` in the activity

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        
        setupDataBinding()
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController
}
```

I didn't add any more configuration, and this is the `error` that pops up when I run the app

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.domain.news/com.domain.news.ui.activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18 in com.domain.news:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #22 in com.domain.news:layout/content_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3446)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2043)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7548)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18 in com.domain.news:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #22 in com.domain.news:layout/content_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22 in com.domain.news:layout/content_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.domain.news.ui.fragments.news.NewsFragment: could not find Fragment constructor
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:563)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:390)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.instantiateFragment(FragmentNavigator.java:132)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:162)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentNavigator.navigate(FragmentNavigator.java:58)
        at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:71)
        at androidx.navigation.NavGraphNavigator.navigate(NavGraphNavigator.java:28)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1049)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.java:633)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:586)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:551)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:533)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1818)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.<init>(FragmentContainerView.java:166)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:51)
2020-09-19 20:39:22.012 16179-16179/com.domain.news E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:335)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1073)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1267)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1267)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:303)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:284)
        at com.domain.news.utils.delegates.ActivityBindingProperty.createActivityBinding(Databinding.kt:20)
        at com.domain.news.utils.delegates.ActivityBindingProperty.getValue(Databinding.kt:16)
        at com.domain.news.ui.activities.MainActivity.getBinding(Unknown Source:10)
        at com.domain.news.ui.activities.MainActivity.setupBinding(MainActivity.kt:42)
        at com.domain.news.ui.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:34)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3282)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3446)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2043)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7548)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.domain.news.ui.fragments.news.NewsFragment.<init> []
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1728)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:548)
            ... 66 more
```

And I can see from the last 3 lines that the reason is because of the fragment constructor

Comment: Can you post the error from logcat. Also show your code on you are using Navigation.findNavController( ) in the fragment.

Comment: @Rajasekhar Sure, I edited the question and added some more details

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: please post nav graph

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the data in the fragment's argument bundle instead of in the constructor.
To do this `NewsSection` needs to implement `Parcelable`

In your navigation xml you can do something like:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/newsFragment"
        android:name="com.example.NewsFragment"
        android:label="ProductListerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_news_secion">
        <argument
            android:name="newsSection"
            app:argType="com.example.NewsSection" />
```

And in the fragment you're navigating from:

```
val newsSection = NewsSection(....)
val bundle = bundleOf("newsSection" to newsSection)
view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.newsAction, bundle)
```

And in `NewsFragment`:

```
val newsSection = arguments?.getParcelable("newsSection") as? NewsSection
```

See https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data for more details.

Comment: Well, that may work without the `ViewPager`, but here I have the `ViewPager adapter` 
if you took a look at `CategoryFragmentPagerAdapter.kt` when I instantiate a new fragment I have to pass an argument to the fragment, and with this approach, I will not be able to pass it using the navigation as the adapter is the responsible for instantiating the fragment, and I can't use the navigation args in there

Comment: You need to rework your fragment so you're not passing anything in the constructor. Fragments require a no-args default constructor to be restored properly, and you get a lint warning about it. The usual approach is having a ``newInstance`` function in a companion object - you call that with your argument, and it creates your Fragment and sets the arguments bundle on it with the data you've passed in. Then you read the arguments during `onCreate`, and set the Fragment up to display whatever. Like the ``DetailsFragment`` bit here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Example

Answer (score 0):

First, open your

`app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation`


The Error Clearly states that it cant inflate your XMl, (Maybe somewhere in line 18 of your @navigation/navigation XML file)

Comment: The Error states that the error is in the `XML layout` not in the navigation file. The line number `18` refers to the `FragmentContainerView` which can't be inflated because of the Args problem